# аналог ispostback в php

Tags: php, c#

В общем вопрос: есть ли аналог ispostback из С# в php? Необходимо узнать загружена ли страница в первый раз или в ответ на действие на форме. В зависимости от этого выводить или скрывать сообщение. Как сделать это в php?

Comment: что означает "или в ответ на действие на форме"? Нотификации нужны?

Comment: методом post отправляю данные в контрол где они обрабатываются и возвращается вью

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```